# Upload file AND other data with AngularJS at the same time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, post, file-upload, sails.js

I want to upload a file and some other user-related data to my sails.js backend.
I can currently upload a file, but when I try to upload some more data at the same time, it fails.
What I try to do is append my $scope.myObj to my FormData but when I do and log the file on my server it doesn't find the file.

This is how I currently upload a file to my server.

```
$scope.uploadFile = function(data) {

    someOtherFormData = angular.copy(data; // I want to send this along with the image

    var fd = new FormData();
    var url = 'xxxxxx';
    var file = $('#fish_image').get(0).files[0];

    fd.append('image', file);

    $http.post(url, fd, {
        transformRequest:angular.identity,
        headers:{'Content-Type':undefined
        }
    }).success(function(data, status, headers){
        $scope.imageURL = data.resource_uri; 
    }).error(function(data, status, headers){

    })
```

Along with my image, i also want to POST my **$scope.myObj** which contains other information from my form.

I'm pretty new to AngularJS and haven't found much related to this issue, so any pointers in the right direction is appreciated. I found some similar threads but most of them aren't quite what I'm looking for..